# Build GDAL with PDF support on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, pdf, gdal, poppler

I'm trying to build GDAL with PDF support on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I've found this [thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-building-with-PDF-driver-on-Windows-td3745729.html) and followed the advice given there:

1. I've downloaded win-kde and checked poppler, lcms & freetype packages for installation.
2. I've checked out gdal trunk and edited nmake.opt to include kde's poppler.lib in the build.

The linker fails with errors like this one:

```
> poppler.lib(JPEG2000Stream.cc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _
> _imp__opj_destroy_decompress@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __th
> iscall JPXStream::close(void)" (?close@JPXStream@@UAEXXZ)
```

These linker errors are preceded by warnings such as this:

```
> poppler.lib(JpegWriter.cc.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _jpeg_f
> inish_compress imported in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall JpegWriter:
> :close(void)" (?close@JpegWriter@@UAE_NXZ)
```

I've tried installing kde's openjpeg package and flagging gdal to build against it, but that fails with compilation errors in openjpeg.

Does anyone know how can I fix these errors, or suggest a better way to build GDAL with PDF support on Windows?